# PHP, explode a text file that have special characters between every sentence

Tags: php, string, text-files, special-characters, explode

I have a text file **with Unicode Encoding ( sometimes it's includes a Hebrew language )** which contents text and between every sentence there is a two special character ( ■■ ) like that ( alt + 2 + 5 + 4 ) this is an sample

```
"How are you, It's a cool day .. how can I read this sentence in a string variable with the quotes."■■

"This is second sentence I want it in another variable or in second cell in array."■■


This is third sentence. It is without quotes I want to read it to a string.■■

This is fourth sentence it includes an enter,
The fourth sentence isn't completed right yet.

The sentence doesn't completed until the special character is appears,


Maybe there a lot of lines in the same sentence.
This is the last part of the sentence■■

"This is the fifth sentence", this is the second part of the fifth sentence■■

Maybe between every two sentences there is a lot of empty lines, This is the sixth sentence■■



Thanks I wish anyone can help me with this, This is the last sentence■■
```

I right this code but it's doesn't work :

```
<?php
$file=file_get_contents("text_file.txt");
$file_= urldecode($file);
$sentences = explode('■■',$file_);
?>
```

**when I make the specified code for the just the first sentence** ( I not putted all the file for easy reading ) I get

```
Array ( [0] => ��"How are you, It s a cool day .. how can I read this sentence in a string variable with the quotes."�%�%
```

And getting the same for the other sentences .. ( I see the all sentences in the same line ) I mean there is no enter

Another thing I want to ignore the lines between two sentences I mean ignore the empty lines after the ■■

Comment: Works for me in all PHP from 5.4 to 7.1

Comment: When I copy your special characters from the question I get  Hex `A6` and not as you suggest Hex `FE` are you sure you are using the correct seperator in your `explode()`??

Comment: What is `urldecode` doing in there? It doesn't look like URL encoded data.

Comment: I am pretty sure that `url_decode()` was not there originally when I first looked at this question. Please annotate any amendments you might make as changing the question ___makes answering it somewhat more difficult___

Comment: Unfortunately we can only guess unless you are **absolutely sure** the seperator you are using is the one in the file. Also it would be useful to know if this character is a simple single byte char set or a multibyte charset?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your fast replies, But I have a Unicode Encoding Text File.
Please see the edited question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution...
I must save the text file as UTF-8 not as Unicode.
Now it works
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [mb_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php) instead of `explode`

Comment: Surely just a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: & #9632; or & #x25A0; instead of ■.

Answer (score -1):

another approach (as it didn't work for me either):

```
<?php

$result = array();
$file = explode("■■", file_get_contents("sentences.txt")); /* EDIT : 2 x ALT254*/
foreach ( $file as $content ) {
$result[] = $content;
}
print_r($result);

?>
```

Comment: What will this achieve?

Comment: same as what he wants (to me, his code is ok but I get nothing with it) that's why I tried to get something in a different maner

Comment: @RiggsFolly : anyway, it did not deserve that -1 imho as I mentionned that it's "another approach (as it didn't work for me either)"

Comment: Like I said, it was not me that downvoted it. I think your code does exactly what OP's does, but I agree it is not worthy of a downvote

Comment: clearly the same ! I try to figure out why his code isn't working as it's good (BTW: i get correct results with ALT254)

Comment: Thanks for the code.. I tried that.. and get the same result as my result in the question code..

Comment: how is your file encoded ? because UTF-8 w/o BOM works.